# Find an invertible matrix U such that UA = R is in reduced row-echelon form , and express U as a product of elementary matrices.

Tags: matrices

Find an invertible matrix $U$ such that $UA = R$ is in reduced row-echelon form , and express $U$ as a
product of elementary matrices.

[image: A]

I have found R(RREF of $A$), but cannot do $U = R * A$ (cannot multiply 4x3 on 4x3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use

- $E_i(c)$ to denote the elementary operation of “multiplying the $i$-th row by $c$” (for $c\ne0$);
- $E_{ij}(d)$ to denote the elementary operation of “adding to the $i$-th row the $j$-th row multiplied by $d$” (for $i\ne j$);
- $E_{ij}$ to denote the elementary operation of “switching the $i$-th and $j$-th rows (for $i\ne j$).

This is convenient because doing the elementary operation on rows is equivalent to multiplying by a matrix, the one obtained by applying the elementary operation to the identity matrix. Such matrices are denoted with the same symbol and are known as *elementary matrices*.

The operations you have to perform on your matrix to get the RREF are, in order,
$$
E_1(1/2)\quad
E_{21}(-3)\quad
E_{31}(-1)\quad
E_{2}(-2/5)\quad
E_{32}(5/2)\quad
E_{12}(-1/2)
$$
and the RREF form is
$$
R=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 7/5 & 1/5 \\
0 & 1 & -7/5 & -2/5 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus we know that
$$
R=
E_{12}(-1/2)
E_{32}(5/2)
E_{2}(-2/5)
E_{31}(-1)
E_{21}(-3)
E_1(1/2)
A
$$